# Free crossword construction programs

Tags: crosswords

I am interested in producing "American style" crosswords and looking for a digital alternative to the graph paper I've been using.

I've tried crossword eclipse but it seems to be more of a generator. It produces grids from a list of words. I want to produce my own grids from scratch.

Comment: @Nai questions about puzzles are just fine here I think. And definitely not in meta. The question about whether this question belongs here are the type of questions that belong on meta.

Comment: @Nai I agree with IvoBeckers. This site is about "the creation and solving of puzzles."  This question certainly fits within that purview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had success just using Excel (or a similar  spreadsheet). Set the row and column widths to be the same, and use a tiny font justified to the top and left to insert the numbers. Change the background "fill" color to black for the squares that are black.

Comment: If you want to automate it you could select all the cells, format their width / height, then create a conditional formatting based on the input 0 or anything, where 0 = black background / text color and anything else = white background and black text. Then save it for use as a template. When you want to print it just select the cells that make up the crossword and print selection / print pdf. When printing change the conditional formatting of the white squares so the text is white too and you have an empty crossword!

Comment: If you're on a Mac, Numbers is also a good alternative (since it's free and Excel isn't).

Comment: @IanMacDonald Similarly, you could use Google Drive's spreadsheet, which is also free.

Comment: Hopefully you find this useful, and if someone wants they can add it to @GentlePurpleRain 's answer. http://www.mediafire.com/download/4cmnnn726u5v3x3/Crossword+Maker.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Short of producing your own grid as Gentle suggests, the crossword construction programs out there that offer full control of the grid itself usually come with a cost. With that said, some of them such as [Crossword Hobbyist](http://www.crosswordhobbyist.com) offer free trials.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  I may be jumping to conclusions but your username suggests you have an affiliation with that site. Please see [Avoid overt self-promotion](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for hints on how to stay within site guidelines while mentioning useful sites or materials you have a stake in. In any case, thanks for contributing and hope you enjoy the site :)